# GoogleMaps API replace content remains gray

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a website using `Bootstrap`.
There is a navigation panel on the left.

Now clicking a navigation button does an `$('#center_div').load(...)` action to load other main contents.

My first content is loaded the same way and it contains a google map object which is displayed correctly.

```
<div>

    <script>

        (function() {

                var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_container');
                console.log(mapCanvas);

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.10957, 8.679543),
                    zoom: 8,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }

                new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

        });

    </script>

<div id="map_container" style="height: 550px"/>

</div>
```

Now loading another content (is working) and switch back to the first content -> the map_container displays a gray rectangle.

Also looking to the network traffic ...
The first time it is loading parts
The second time nothing happens

Any ideas?

---

#### Edit 1

Ok I try to explain it a litte more.

My Website is devided in a toolbar, navigation and content section.

The content section is replaced with this javascript function ...

```
Test.loadContent = function (url, success, target, update) {

    console.log('loading ' + url);

    var content = target ? $(target) : $(Test.page);

    var data = {
        updateId: update ? update : content.attr('id')
    };

    content.hide().empty().load(url, data, function (responseText, statusText, xhr) {

        if (xhr.status == 403 || xhr.status == 401) {
            Test.loadContent("/login/auth");
        } else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            content.html(responseText);
        }

        content.fadeIn(250, function () {

            if (success) {
                success(responseText);
            }

        });

    });

};

Test.map.initMap = function (target) {

    console.log('building Map');

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.10957, 8.679543),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    Test.map.instance = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(target), mapOptions);

};
```

Now I am loading my page snipped with this function.
The snipped looks like this

```
<div>

    <script>

        $(function () {

            var target = $('#map_content');
            target.height(500);

            Test.map.initMap('map_content');

        });

    </script>

    <div id="map_content"></div>

</div>
```

So the onReady functions triggers the actual building of the map.

The first time everything goes well.
But after loading another content and comming back to the page where the map is included the map remains gray.

First load:
[image]

Second load:
[image]

The google maps API is included in my header section which does not change during the content refresh.

---

#### Edit 2

I just noticed that resizing the browser window brings up the map again.

But executing

```
google.maps.event.trigger(Test.map.instance, "resize");
```

did not help to solve the problem

Comment: My guessing is that it's related to the `ajax` call - the script not runing after the `ajax` request BUT It's quite hard to answer this question without see the full code or (even better) a snippet or fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found the solution :)

I had to call

```
google.maps.event.trigger(Test.map.instance, "resize");
```

But calling it directly after creating the map did not work (probably to early)
Using a setTimeout(..., 1000) worked but is not deterministic.

A clean solution is to fire the event if the 'idle' event occured.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Test.map.instance, 'idle', function () {
    console.log('idle occured!');
    google.maps.event.trigger(Test.map.instance, "resize");
});
```